# Bootstrap create third menu level with AdminLTE css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently using the [AdminLTE](https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE) template.

But I'm struggling with a third level menu. I've just tried with and without this plugin I'm using and I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong, because my third level menu does not show up.

[Here's the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c2H4S/).

And also a image that shows what's going on.
[image]

I've read that since bootstrap 3 the `dropdown-submenu` was implemented, and I've tried to use it, without any success.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
      <a tabindex="-1" href="#">More options</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
          <a href="#">More..</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've searched around google and [I found this example](http://www.bootply.com/muHAhEyfz4#), which is the one I'm trying to implement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, bootstrap3 has no default multi-level dropdown functionality. What you are using as markup is taken from this "[extension](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3)".

You are simply lacking the according CSS for this dropdown solution:

Add this to your stylesheet:

```
.dropdown-submenu {
position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
top: 0;
left: 100%;
margin-top: -6px;
margin-left: -1px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
display: block;
content: " ";
float: right;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-color: transparent;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
border-left-color: #ccc;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
border-left-color: #fff;
}
```

[Your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c2H4S/1/)

Comment: Worked perfectly. I didn't know it was an extension. Thank you.